# How to hide XAML TextBlock with VisualStateManager?

Tags: xaml, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I would like to hide a TextBlock based on the pages Visual State. I use the VisualStateManager to change states wich works fine. But my code for hiding the TextBlock somehow does not.
Additional question: if two states share the same instructions (like Narrow and Snapped), is there a way not to write the same ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames-tags again, so the amount of code to maintain gets reduced? Thanks

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Title" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiLight" Margin="12,0,0,1"
                                   Text="{Binding TitleTextBlockText}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!-- Visual states reflect the application's window size -->
                                <VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DefaultLayout">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Visible
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Visible
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Visible
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Visible
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Filled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Visible
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>

                                    <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Collapsed
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="Title">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        Visibility.Collapsed
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this (e.g. in a template of a custom control), you shall wrap the textbloc into grid. You cannot animate an object like this because the visualstatemanager cannot be inside of the object which will be animated by the visualstatemanager itself.
In the control's generic template, something like this:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NumericField}">
          <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup Name="ValidationStates">
                <VisualState Name="Good">
                  <!-- do your things -->
              </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Border x:Name="ValidationBorderPart"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1">
              <TextBox x:Name="ValuePart"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       BorderBrush="Transparent"
                       BorderThickness="0"
                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:NumericField}},Path=Representation, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Border>

          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```